# Print Multiple Table on Main Panel of R Shiny

Tags: r, shiny

I am writing a R shiny app where I have a Ui. R which provides the user to select multiple options, each of the option is mapped to to read a tab delimited file which has two columns data.

All I want it to have a main table with tabs where one of the tab prints the tables (as selected by the user) one below the other.
Here Is my code:

```
Ui.R
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel(strong(" ", style="color:black"), windowTitle="T2P"),

  sidebarPanel(

    tags$head(        
        tags$style(type='text/css', "input { width: 100px; }"),# control numericInput box        ,        
        tags$style(type='text/css', "select,textarea,.jslider,.well { background-color: #F0F0F0; } ")
        ),


     selectInput("var", 
      label = (strong("Choose Feature DataSets for Analysis", style="color:black")),
      choices = c(" ","Gene Ontology", "PFAM",
        "SecondaryStructures", "PeptideStats"),
      selected = "", multiple=TRUE)

     ),


     mainPanel(  


        tags$head(
                    tags$style(type = "text/css", "a{color: black;}")
                ),  
        list(tags$head(tags$style("body {background-color: #F5F5F5; }"))),

        ##
        tabsetPanel(id="tabSelected",
            tabPanel("Introduction", style="color:black",
                h1("Introduction"),
                textOutput("myselection"),
                br()

                 # tableOutput("myGO")

            ),
            tabPanel("Table", style="color:black",
                h1("Table"),

                # tableOutput("myselection2Table")

                    tableOutput("myGO"),

                # br(),
                tableOutput("myPFAM")


            )           
        )
    )
)
)


server.R
shinyServer(
  function(input, output) 
  {

    output$myGO <- renderTable({
     myGOdata <- {
        if (input$var %in% "Gene Ontology")
        {
            data.frame(read.table("GO.txt", sep="\t",header=TRUE))
        }
    }

    })

    output$myPFAM <- renderTable({
        if (input$var %in% "PFAM")
        {
            data.frame(read.table("PFAM.txt", sep="\t",header=TRUE))
        }
    })  
 }
)
```

Comment: Hi, and what are your problems? What is the question? If you are playing with Gene Ontologies see [bioconductor](http://www.bioconductor.org) page, maybe you found something of your interest, if you had not already done it.

Answer (score 3):

In your conditions "if (input$var %in% "PFAM")" you test one by one, if each element of "input$var" is in "PFAM", then it returns one boolean for each elements.

`If` statement can't deal with an expression which returns several booleans, that's why you probably get a warning like this : `Warning in if (input$var %in% "Gene Ontology") { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used`

Reverse your test, it should be : "if ("Gene Ontology" %in% input$var)". You need to test if "Gene Ontology" is in "input$var" and not the contrary.

Normaly, it should work now.

Comment: Thanks Julien Navarre.